# Target negation not working in Spring AOP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

We use spring boot and have implemented additional Actuator Endpoints by implementing MVCEndpoint. We also apply AOP to @RequestMapping methods to monitor response times.

I have these 2 classes:

```
public class ControllerStub {
    @RequestMapping("/controller")
    public String method(String arg) {
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

And

```
 public class MyMvcEndpoint implements MvcEndpoint, Endpoint {
    @Override
    public String getPath() {
        return "path";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSensitive() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.Endpoint> getEndpointType() {
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/mvcEndpoint")
    public String method(){
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

And the following aspect:

```
@Around("@annotation(requestMapping) && !target(org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MvcEndpoint)")
    public Object process(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, RequestMapping requestMapping) throws Throwable {
        return timeExecution(joinPoint);
    }
```

Which is intended to wrap all @RequestMapping methods except the ones in a MvcEndpoint and it doesn't work as I would expect. It indeed filters out the MVCEndpoint. But it doesn't wrap ControllerStub in a proxy.

I started debugging and I was able to trace it down to RuntimeTestWalker and ShadowMatch. Looks like the negation is indeed composited using an aspectJ Not which in turn wraps an aspectJ InstanceOf expression. In ShadowMatch the residualTest is

```
!((Var org.waterford.core.webapp.integrationtests.ControllerStub) instanceof org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MvcEndpoint)
```

However, I don't see where the negation is applied. Looks to me like the result returns false the moment the instanceof check fails without being negated.

I landed in TestVisitorAdapter on the method which visits the Not expression:

```
@Override
public void visit(Not e) {
  e.getBody().accept(this);
}
```

I don't understand all of the AspectJ mechanisms but I would expect that in the implementation of RuntimeTestWalker.visit(Not e) it would have to negate the result after it tests the body. The body for me is the instanceof check.

I'm using spring-boot 1.2.5.RELEASE and AspectJ Weaver 1.8.7. Looks like RuntimeTestWalker's coming from spring-aop-4.2.1.RELEASE for me.